# Using C++ code to Check in OS if WiFi is available or not(if its available whether its turn ON/OFF)

Tags: c++

Is there any method or function or anything available in c++ to check or get status of WiFi is available in Windows OS?
If its available then i need to check or get status whether WiFi is ON/OFF?
If any suggestion?

Comment: That would be OS specific. C++ does not have any WiFi management.

Comment: You can inspect `/proc/net/wireless` on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easy way is to run some bash/command line script from C/C++ that return some knownv alue for WiFi status.

For windows there is netsh and for linux iwconifg/ifconfig, plus some scripts lines and you will get what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Using Netsh script helping me to get more information.